# Sharepoint: Combining Javascript files stored in "Style Library"?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, sharepoint

For the sake of client-side performance, it's best to minimize the number HTTP requests to load a page. Is it possible to combine the contents of all Javascript files stored in the "Style Library" such that the client only has to make one request instead traditionally, a request for each Javascript file?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, an out of the box Style Library doesn't contain any javascript files. What files are you referring to?